# Retrieve name based on object _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following schema in my Node js / express app where each warehouse can optionally have a parent warehouse. I wrote the code to save warehouse, but can't figure out how to retrieve any warehouse (which has a parent) and get its parent warehouse name...so was wondering if there is any way I can do that in one call? Thanks

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var warehouseSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    parentID: { type: String, ref: 'Warehouse' }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Warehouse', warehouseSchema);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just [as `Philipp` said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27175758/1202461), you can't do it with a single MongoDB auery.

But you can do it with single Mongoose command, using its [Query Population feature](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html):

```
Warehouse.findById(warehouse_id).populate('parentID').exec(function(err, doc) {
  if (err) {
    // something get wrong
  } else {
    // doc.parentID is a parrent Warehouse here
  }
})
```

Internally, Mongoose will make two separate queries to MongoDB (one for the child document, and then another for its parent), bu for you it'll look like a single command.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB can't do JOINs on the database. As long as the parent is a reference in the warehouse object, you can not retrieve both with one query. You first have to query the warehouse(s) and then resolve the reference(s) with a second query.

To avoid the second query you might want to look into embedding the required information about the parent-document in the child-document. Duplicate information in MongoDB isn't as abnormal as in a relational database.

Comment: Thanks Philipp for your help, appreciate it